# Writing INSERT query in the __construct() function

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a insert query (for increasing the number of *viewed* for each post). Now I want to know, writing that query in the `__construct()` is a normal thing? Is it not bad? (because I read somewhere it is not a good idea)

```
class classname {

    private $post_id;
    public function __construct($post_id) {

        $this->post_id = $post_id;

        INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed (post_id, username) 
                           VALUES ($this->post_id, $_SESSION['username']);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer, but I can confirm that's an horrible idea. Read about doing work in constructors, the Single Responsibility principle and entities persistence ignorance.

Comment: @plalx please *(if you can)* write an answer and explain more. Also I like to know your solution for doing that. thanks

Comment: @Shafizadeh Simply put, logging views is a cross cutting concern that should be handled at the service boundaries of the specific workflow it applies to. If there's an Application Layer that's where it would go. If the MVC controller serves as the application layer then that's where it should go. Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are creating instances of this Class. Since you want to track the views of your blog post, you will need to make sure the following -

1. Only one instance of this class is created for each user if a blog post is viewed
2. Creating multiple instances of same class will result in getting wrong numbers tracked.
3. You can also put a check in place before inserting the data into database whether it's already been tracked.

Comment: Yes there is just one instance of that class. Also there is a unique-group on both `post_id` and `username` that prevents of duplicate viewed rows.

Comment: Just for code organization, you may want to create a private function inside of the class for the query execution.

Comment: agreed with @BrandonWhite

Comment: @BrandonWhite Why?! in this case OP have to execute that method every time after getting an instance of that class. But putting `INSERT` query in the `__construct()` makes it *(query)* execute automatically for ever.

Comment: @Shafizadeh That is only assuming the query is the only thing happening in the constructor. If more than one operation is occurring, it could get hectic. Good organization is key to editing down the road.

Comment: That's an horrible design idea which violates so many principles. How do you expect to unit test this? What about the Single Responsibility principle? What about the well-known fact that work shouldn't be done in constructors: it's role is to initialize the fields of an object in order to bring it in a valid state, nothing more. Not only this, but it's also semantically incorrect: creating a new object doesn't mean "viewing" it in any means. It's not because that's currently the only reason you instantiate this object that it won't change.